# OutputClaimTransformation in B2C SAML2 CustomPolicy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have some b2c SAML CustomPolicy for one SP.
Here I have some OutputClaims. Now I want to send one Claim with some logic and tried to set OutputClaimTransformations.

My scenario:
I will send the claim "ABCString: 0,1" for Croatia and "ABCString: 0,2" for germany. 0 is some default value I need to send and the next value should be country dependent.
So I created one Transformation for defaultvalue, then one for country dependent, then I merge both in one collection and will join them in one string.
I attached my XML.

Problem is: the "ABCString" is never sent to application. The OutputClaims of the ClaimsTransformations are not used at all.
All examples I found were in Extension or Base File and are using "persistent" fields. I just want to build the value on request.

Some ideas for this?

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_signin_xxx-test"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://xxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_xxx-test" >

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>xxx.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

    <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="ABCCollection">
        <DisplayName>abc</DisplayName>
        <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>abc.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="ABCString">
        <DisplayName>abcs</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>abcs.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="DEFString">
        <DisplayName>defs</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>defs</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="GHIString">
        <DisplayName>ghis</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>ghis.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="SetDefault" TransformationMethod="AddParameterToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ABCString" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="item" DataType="string" Value="0" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ABCCollection" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetCountrySpecific" TransformationMethod="LookupValue">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_country" TransformationClaimType="inputParameterId" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="CROATIA" DataType="string" Value="1" />
          <InputParameter Id="GERMANY" DataType="string" Value="2" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="DEFString" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="MergeDefaultWithCountry" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="DEFString" TransformationClaimType="item" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ABCCollection" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ABCCollection" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="ConvertTeamCollectionToString" TransformationMethod="StringJoin">
        <InputClaims>
         <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ABCCollection" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter DataType="string" Id="delimiter" Value="," />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ABCString" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>

    </ClaimsTransformations>
        <ContentDefinitions>
            <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
                <LoadUri>https://api.contoso.com/test/azure/html/xxx.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
        </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>

    <ClaimsProviders>
        <ClaimsProvider>
            <Domain>app.contoso.com</Domain>
            <DisplayName>SAML2 for App</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="Saml2App">
                    <DisplayName>SAML2 for App</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="None" />
                    <OutputTokenFormat>SAML2</OutputTokenFormat>
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="IssuerUri">https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_xxx-test</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="MetadataSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_mycert"/>
                        <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_mycert"/>
                        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_mycert"/>
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <InputClaims/>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml"/>
                </TechnicalProfile>

                <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-Saml">
                    <DisplayName>Session Management Provider</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.SamlSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>
    </ClaimsProviders>

    <UserJourneys>
        <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInSAML2App">
            <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

                <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="Saml2App" />

            </OrchestrationSteps>
            <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
        </UserJourney>

    </UserJourneys>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInSAML2App" />
        <UserJourneyBehaviors>
          <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
        </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?><some definition>]]></Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Item>
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy</Item>
        <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="MetadataSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_mycert"/>
        <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_mycert"/>
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_mycert"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="GHIString" DefaultValue="123" /> 
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_country" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetCountrySpecific" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetDefault" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="MergeDefaultWithCountry" />
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ConvertTeamCollectionToString" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="Email" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" ExcludeAsClaim="false"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe any output claims transformations are invoked for a relying party technical profile.

Rather, you must invoke the output claims transformations during the user journey, such as follows.

1. Define a new [claims transformation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile) that invokes the new output claims transformation:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimsTransformation-CreateABCStringClaim">
  <DisplayName>Create ABCString Claim</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ABCString" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetCountrySpecific" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetDefault" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="MergeDefaultWithCountry" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ConvertTeamCollectionToString" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

2. Add a new orchestration step, before the **SendClaims** orchestration step, that invokes the claims transformation technical profile:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="ClaimsTransformation-CreateABCStringClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-CreateABCStringClaim" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Works great when adding it to claimsexchange userjourney.